# iOS - Refresh Control - "Attempting to change the refresh control while it is not idle is strongly discouraged and probably won't work properly."

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, pull-to-refresh

I cannot find many references to this warning anywhere. I have two view controllers that offer pull-to-refresh control. One is fine. The other produces the warning above. I copied the code from one to the other.

The code is as follows (PFUser refers to Parse.com):

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"who's the user: %@", [PFUser currentUser]);


        UIRefreshControl *refreshTable = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
        refreshTable.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"One sec... refreshing"];
        [refreshTable addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.refreshControl = refreshTable;

    } else {
```

Has anyone else encountered this? and is there a work-around/fix?

Comment: How about doing it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you. If you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it complete. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it helped. I've written it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it inside `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this warning popped up since I was doing `collectionView.refreshControl = nil` while `refreshControl` was animating. Calling **`refreshControl.endRefreshing()`** before doing that eliminated the warning.