# UIRefreshControl will dismiss on all phones except iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using an instance of `UIRefreshControl` to reload the data in a `UITableView`.

If I run the app on any phone except the iPhone 6+, the refresh-control will disappear after the data refresh has finished.

However, if I run the app, on the iPhone 6+, the refresh-control will stay visible *after* the user has pulled down on the table-view to refresh the data. Below is a screenshot of the refresh-control visible behind elements of the table-view:

[image]

This behavior does not occur on any other phone except for the 6+. Below is the code for refreshing the table-view data, which is inside of `viewWillAppear`:

```
    if (self.refreshControl == nil) {
        UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
        refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor refreshColor];
        [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

        self.tableView.backgroundView.layer.zPosition -= 1;
    }
```

Does anyone know why the refresh control will stay visible when refreshing a table-view on the 6+?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint in?

Comment: I get a warning (just as I do when running the app) of " Attempting to change the refresh control while it is not idle is strongly discouraged and probably won't work properly."

Answer (score 1):

According to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19480549/224988) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480424/how-do-i-hide-a-uirefreshcontrol), you have to manually remove and disconnect the refresh control.

That feels hack, and indeed, [several[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296028/ios-refresh-control-attempting-to-change-the-refresh-control-while-it-is-no) [places[2]](https://github.com/cooloon/7-TopPlaces/commit/d2afed511015ddfe93771fa285ee17088a5568b9) [on the internet[3]](http://w3facility.org/question/ios-refresh-control-attempting-to-change-the-refresh-control-while-it-is-not-idle-is-strongly-discouraged-and-probably-wont-work-properly/) seem to suggest calling `endRefreshing` inside of `viewDidLoad`. Some variations call for removing the refresh control and others say to endRefreshing instead.

Since I'm unsure which works, and because it probably depends on what your view controller looks like, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Hey Moshe, thanks again for your help and answer. I tried the answers in the links you shared, but unfortunately; have not had any success yet. More investigation needed I suppose. I'll be sure to post here when I learn the solution!

Comment: Sorry to hear that you didn't solve the problem yet! I'm out of ideas for now, short of a code escalation with the Apple folks, but that's your choice. That, or file a radar. ;)

Comment: Might not be a bad idea, actually. What's the difference between 'code escalation and filing a radar? Thanks again!

Comment: You're allowed to request code-level support twice per membership year from Apple. Filing a radar is simply filing a bug on bugreport.apple.com. The code level incidents are actually better for this kind of thing, only because there isn't too much info available online.